# Как проверить открыто окно через window.open() или нет?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть два localhost.

```
http://localhost:8110 [1]
http://localhost:6040 [2]
```

[1] открывает окно [2]

```
window.open(`http://localhost:8110`,`test`,...)
```

окно открывается и устанавливается соединение....

Но мне сейчас потребовалось проверить на [2]

Было окно вызванно window.open() или нет.

Я могу сделать проверку window.opener. Существует или нет.

Но проблема в том, что если я хочу его проверить у меня появляется ошибка.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8110" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at console.log (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:8110/import:20:13
```

origin не могу проверить, потому что есть вариант, что он будет но окно инициализируется не window.open()

Есть ли какой нибудь параметр проверки ?

Дополнение:

Почему возникает ошибка Blocked a frame with origin.

1 - [1] В первом окне открывается второе.

```
 let newWindow =   window.open(`http://localhost:8110`,`test`,...)
```

Дождаться того, что бы оно открылось, я не могу.
В интернете в примерах написанно.

```
newWindow.onload = () => {....}
```

Это не работает с кроссдоменным запросом. Или я что то не понимаю.

2 - Открывается окно [2]

В этом окне я вызываю метод

```
window.opener.postMessage('init', `[1]`)
```

Сообщение отсылается в родительское окно и дальше могу обратно отправить уже данные из родительского окна.

Но проверить сущетсвует или нет opener во втором окне я не могу.

Comment: Напишите как вы проверяете. Я вот проверил, и кроссдоменный opener просто является прокси-объектом для window, и ошибок никаких нет. if( window.opener ) не подходит?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev кстати, я в проекте пробовал использовать window.opener, он не сработал. не знаю, почему, мне кажется, я сравнивал window c window.top, или чтото такое. Может, это зависит от того как создается окно

Comment: Написал, как я делаю. Всё работает. но для этого надо и из открываемого окна запрос в родительское послать. И проблемы бы в этом небыло, если бы у меня окно не могло в iframe открываться. (там  window.opener = undefined)